# Mysql row count returning incorrect values for joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Good day all. I am working on retrieving data from the database across some tables.

My query is shown below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT applicable_areas.area, applicable_areas.id as id,  count(distinct supreme_applicable_areas.applicable_area_id) as supreme_court_cases, count(distinct appeal_applicable_areas.applicable_area_id) as appeal_court_cases
FROM `applicable_areas`
JOIN appeal_applicable_areas ON appeal_applicable_areas.applicable_area_id = applicable_areas.id
JOIN supreme_applicable_areas ON supreme_applicable_areas.applicable_area_id = applicable_areas.id
JOIN cp_cases_counsel ON ( (cp_cases_counsel.suitno = supreme_applicable_areas.suitno) OR (cp_cases_counsel.suitno = appeal_applicable_areas.suitno)) 
WHERE cp_cases_counsel.counsel_id = 54
GROUP BY applicable_areas.area, applicable_areas.id
ORDER BY applicable_areas.area ASC;
```

It seems as if it checks for the occurrence of values from the 'supreme_applicable_areas' table and if found, goes ahead to check for that on the 'appeal_applicable_areas' table. So, if there is no value for supreme, but there is for appeal, it brings results for both supreme and appeal. However I want it to pick one or the other.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide relevant schema definition, sample data, expected result. Without those things we will be largely guessing. Thanks.

Comment: First, what is the result of: **`SELECT version();`**  Next, your SQL obviously does not represent your requirement.  It seems you've been trying "stuff" to "get the right answer".  Can you describe the two different `counts` you're trying to obtain?  Keep it simple.  Right now, your SQL would likely produce a 1 for each group, since you have `COUNT(DISTINCT group_by_term)`.  This can't be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7946066075101252e600c8f5955cc62)

Here's a guess, based on the detail provided.

This solution avoids the `JOIN` issues by deriving a slightly better structure for this case, where the appeals and supreme applicable areas are combined in one table, with an indicator column for each type, (1, null) or (null, 1) to allow counting without conditional logic.  The nulls are just ignored when counting each type (`stype` and `atype`) separately.

This could be done in a few different ways.  This is one.

**The SQL (For MySQL 8.0+):**

```
WITH area_types (atype, stype, applicable_area_id, suitno) AS (
       SELECT    1, null, applicable_area_id, suitno FROM appeal_applicable_areas
        UNION
       SELECT null,    1, applicable_area_id, suitno FROM supreme_applicable_areas
     )
SELECT applicable_areas.area
     , applicable_areas.id as id
     , count(stype) as supreme_court_cases
     , count(atype) as appeal_court_cases
  FROM applicable_areas
  JOIN area_types
    ON area_types.applicable_area_id = applicable_areas.id
  JOIN cp_cases_counsel
    ON cp_cases_counsel.suitno = area_types.suitno
 WHERE cp_cases_counsel.councel_id = 54
 GROUP BY applicable_areas.id
 ORDER BY applicable_areas.area ASC
;
```

and because I made `id` the `primary key` of `applicable_areas`, we really didn't need `area` in the `GROUP BY` terms (See: `functional dependence`).  I've removed that.

**For MySQL prior to 8.0:**

```
SELECT applicable_areas.area
     , applicable_areas.id as id
     , count(stype) as supreme_court_cases
     , count(atype) as appeal_court_cases
  FROM applicable_areas
  JOIN (
           SELECT    1 AS atype, null AS stype, applicable_area_id, suitno FROM appeal_applicable_areas
            UNION
           SELECT null         ,    1         , applicable_area_id, suitno FROM supreme_applicable_areas
       ) AS area_types
    ON area_types.applicable_area_id = applicable_areas.id
  JOIN cp_cases_counsel
    ON cp_cases_counsel.suitno = area_types.suitno
 WHERE cp_cases_counsel.councel_id = 54
 GROUP BY applicable_areas.id
 ORDER BY applicable_areas.area ASC
;
```

**The result, given some random data:**

```
+------+----+---------------------+--------------------+
| area | id | supreme_court_cases | appeal_court_cases |
+------+----+---------------------+--------------------+
| 1001 |  1 |                   1 |                  1 |
| 1002 |  2 |                   1 |                  1 |
| 1003 |  3 |                   0 |                  1 |
| 1004 |  4 |                   0 |                  2 |
| 1005 |  5 |                   1 |                  0 |
| 1006 |  6 |                   1 |                  0 |
| 1007 |  7 |                   3 |                  0 |
+------+----+---------------------+--------------------+
```

**The setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE applicable_areas        (id int primary key auto_increment, area int);
CREATE TABLE appeal_applicable_areas (applicable_area_id int, suitno int);
CREATE TABLE supreme_applicable_areas(applicable_area_id int, suitno int);
CREATE TABLE cp_cases_counsel        (suitno int, councel_id int);

INSERT INTO applicable_areas (area) VALUES
    ( 1001)
  , ( 1002)
  , ( 1003)
  , ( 1004)
  , ( 1005)
  , ( 1006)
  , ( 1007)
;

INSERT INTO appeal_applicable_areas (applicable_area_id, suitno) VALUES
    ( 1, 2001)
  , ( 2, 2002)
  , ( 3, 2003)
  , ( 4, 2004)
  , ( 4, 2009)
  , ( 4, 2010)
;

INSERT INTO supreme_applicable_areas (applicable_area_id, suitno) VALUES
    ( 1, 3001)
  , ( 2, 3002)
  , ( 5, 3003)
  , ( 6, 3004)
  , ( 7, 3005)
  , ( 7, 3006)
  , ( 7, 3007)
  , ( 7, 3008)
;

INSERT INTO cp_cases_counsel (suitno, councel_id) VALUES
    ( 2001,   54)
  , ( 2002,   54)
  , ( 2003,   54)
  , ( 2004,   55)
  , ( 2008,   54)
  , ( 2009,   54)
  , ( 2010,   54)
  , ( 3001,   54)
  , ( 3002,   54)
  , ( 3003,   54)
  , ( 3004,   54)
  , ( 3005,   66)
  , ( 3006,   54)
  , ( 3007,   54)
  , ( 3008,   54)
  , ( 3009,   54)
  , ( 3010,   54)
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jon. I appreciate this. It worked

Comment: @Korlahwarleh and, of course, you can now process more than one `councel` at a time, generating their counts in separate groups.  Just add `councel_id` to the `GROUP BY`, `SELECT` list and `ORDER BY` clauses.